# Passing laravel user create data into stored procedure

Tags: php, laravel

I have a stored procedure that I'm trying to call in laravel using the data from the user model upon creation. The procedure runs fine manually with the 2 parameters. As far as the procedure is concerned, the first parameter is a CHAR, 20 and the second is an integer.

So once the user is saved, I'm simply getting the status and the newly created ID, passing them into the method call as the parameters for the procedure, and then executing the procedure.

When this happens, I don't get any errors but the record is not updating and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I'm thinking it could potentially have to do with the data types but I can't see why it wouldn't work with what I have

Is there something I'm missing?

```
 $user->save();

 //This dumps the correct values
 dd($user->status . $user->id);

 $updateUser = new userInfo();
 $updateUserInfo = $updateUser->updateUserStatus($user->status,$user->id);
 function updateUserStatus(string $status, $userID){
    $stmt = \DB::connection('odbc')->getPdo()->prepare('CALL UPDATE_STATUS(?,?)'); 
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $status, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I execute stored procedures:

```
DB::select('call UPDATE_STATUS(?, ?)', [ $status, $userID ]);
```

Comment: I'm calling several other procedures this way though, and they work fine. This one, although no errors, just isn't updating

Comment: Have you tried using `try - catch` block to make sure that it does not silently fails?

Comment: I put a try/catch around it like so ```}catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }``` but still the page loads and no update on the database @nakov

Comment: have you tried another way of updating it, for example the one that I have given above, just to make sure that it is not something in your code? Because I am out of other ideas, the example I have given is the way I use stored procedures and it works fine for me.

Comment: Ok I tried how you have above and finally got it after realizing I needed to remove the length argument from the parameters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can call the procedure this way.

```
function updateUserStatus(string $status, $userID){ 
  $stmt = \DB::SELECT('CALL UPDATE_STATUS($status, $userID)');
}
```